# How is memory handled in android?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app for android and I'm coming from a `C++` background, but it looks like there aren't any explicit memory handling. Naturally I'm worried about memory leak so I'm wondering how memory is handled on `Android`.

Comment: "I'm wondering how memory is handled on Android" -- please be **much** more specific, as this is entirely too broad. There are whole book chapters on Linux and Android memory management.

Comment: I'm assuming that when the app is closed using onStop(). Specifically, I'm wondering whether or not the memory for variables is automatically freed when an app is put into standby mode, or if it persists until the app is closed permanently. In other words, can I use variables that were set during the active mode to time the app during the standby mode?

Comment: That would depend on what "variables" you are referring to and what "is closed permanently" means. "I'm assuming that when the app is closed using onStop()." -- no. `onStop()` is an [activity lifecycle callback method](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle). It is called when an activity is stopped (i.e., it no longer is visible).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for explicit memory handling, because the [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) will take care of variables that are not in use anymore.

To understand the onStop() function you should have a look at the [activity lifecircle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png). There you can see that the activity (also you variable) still exists after the onStop() has been called. If a App with higher priority (e.g. the app that is shown on the display) needs more memory or your App is closed ( onDestroyed() is called), then your variable automatically will be destroyed and the memory will be freed.